# Worksheets.Count in VBA is returning the wrong number of pages

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data workbook with a number of worksheets (3 to be exact). I would like to copy the data from each worksheet and add them all in one worksheet (append one before the other) in a second workbook. All the worksheets have the same format and same columns, so I can condidently do it without worrying about data consistency. The problem is that the for loop I am using runs the code 21 times even though I only have 3 worksheets, and no copying and pasting takes place. I used MsgBox to debug. The following is the code, written in VBA editor of Excel 2013 on a Windows OS:

```
Sub compileData()
    ' compile all the data in one worksheet

    ' defining variables
    Dim i As Integer

    ' copy the headers
    Windows("source_file.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A3:K3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("target_file.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ' So far, so good! The header was copied & pasted with no problem.

    For i = 1 To Workbooks("source_file.xlsx").Worksheets.Count

        ' copy data from source worksheet
        Windows("source_file.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Range("A4:K4").End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Copy

        ' paste data
        Windows("target_file.xlsx").Activate
        Sheets(1).Activate
        Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Next i

    MsgBox i      ' this returns 21 while source_file.xlsx has only 3 worksheets

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have hidden sheets? What if you dim j and set it equal to the count, does that return 21?

Comment: just try with MsgBox Worksheets.Count and see what it says. does target_file.xlsx have 21 sheets?

Comment: You should also be consistent with `Sheets` and `Worksheets` in your code.  Technically `Sheets` can contain more objects than `Worksheets` since `Sheets` is allowed to contain any `Chart` objects which have been added as sheets.  `Worksheets` excludes these.  The two counts (and indices) can be different.  I suspect your issue is something hidden since you are using `Worksheets` to start the loop.

Comment: If you want to see what `Worksheets` exist, they are listed in the tree view with the code modules.  Expand `Microsoft Excel Objects` for the given workbook and you should be able to eyeball how many are in there.  3 and 21 will look quite different.

Comment: Add `debug.print i & ": " & Sheets(i).Name` in your loop. It may help you to find what happens. Another point: you don't need to Activate and Select for a Copy/Paste. The Range object Copy method has an argument called Destination (see the inline help)

Comment: Thank you all for the points. I had removed 18 worksheets from this file, and for some reason, it was counting those. I created a file by copying the worksheets into a new workbook and applied the code to the new file. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if this question has been resolved or not so...
I don't know the reason why, but for me it works if you activate the workbook in which you are counting the sheets before invoking the sheets.count.
I know, you explicitly told it in which workbook to count the sheets, but for some reason this has happened to me before also, and is resolved by activating the workbook explicitly before counting the sheets.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Richard. The issue was resolved, and my solution appears in the very last comment after the question.